# Using ' sign in python String

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I am writting an SQL query with such sign: ' but interpreter sees as a start if string.
I try to make following `'String1'+%s'+'String2'`
how can a get

> String1 ' String2?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use double quotes:

```
>>> s = "String1 ' String2"
>>> s
"String1 ' String2"
```

Single and double-quotes are mostly interchangeable when defining strings.

Comment: You can also escape the symbol: `'String 1 \' String 2'`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry, I started typing before yeputons posted, so there was redundancy.
However, I would still like to point out that while both methods work, Oin's answer is considered best practice.